# Power BI - Identifying orders with different Unit Price for same product code

Tags: powerbi

All

Hope you can help. Firstly I apologise if my data is not coming out in a structured format (I am new to stack overflow as well as power bi). Here is a snapshot of my data;

```
Row     Customer#     Order#    Order Date      Product Code      Unit Price      Quantity         
1       1100          565       5 Aug 2020        A312             100.00           10
2       1100          565       5 Aug 2020        A312               0.00            5
3       2200          711       2 Aug 2020        A943             523.00            7
4       4565          502       9 Aug 2020        B523             235.00            4
```

My data is really large, spanning various countries and multiple months. But it includes alot of the type in row 3 and 4 above (simple one line order), however it also includes orders in row 1 & 2 above (same order number, same customer, same product, different unit price).

I am trying to identify orders like in row 1 & 2, I do not want a total of the order lines, I want a list of all orders like this, and then I can work with it further. Is there any easy way in Power BI to perform this task?

I have searched previous questions, but I only get information on identifying duplicates, group by and index. Is this the way to go or is there an easier way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks everyone
JoJo

Answer (score 1):

You can first add a column which indicates how many rows there are for that customer and order:

```
CountCustOrders = 
var curCust = Dups[Customer]
var curOrder = Dups[Order]
return CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Dups), FILTER(Dups, curCust = Dups[Customer] && curOrder = Dups[Order]))
```

If you want them in a seperate table, you can click "new table" and add teh following:

```
ManyRows = FILTER(Dups, Dups[CountCustOrders] > 1)
```